# Asp.Net 4.5 Consume Service Reference with windows authentication and default credentials

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-authentication

I have a web application on my intranet configured to use windows authentication on IIS. We have a windows network and an active dircory server, so when some user try to access the application the browser doesn't ask for login and password because it uses the windows credentials of the current logged user.

I added a webservice in this application and tried to consume it in an windows application. I got an error 401 when I tried. The users are already logged on windows  with  their own credentials, so I'd like to have my windows application logging into the webservice using current user's credentials.

My Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MyWebServices
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for TestWS
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class TestWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

My console Application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyWebServiceClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TWS.TestWSSoapClient svc = new TWS.TestWSSoapClient();
            try
            {

                Console.WriteLine(svc.HelloWorld());
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

both are .net framework 4.5

Sorry about my poor English :)

Answer (score 0):

I found it. 
I needed to create a basic http binding and set it's client credential type to Windows. It works with ntlm too.

I had to create an endpont address to and pass both http binding and endpoint address to my SoapClient constructor.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{


    try
    {
        System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding MyHttpBinding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);                                            
        MyHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        //MyHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;  //works too
        System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress MyAuthASMXWebServiceAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost/TestWS.asmx"));
        TWS.TestWSSoapClient svc = new TWS.TestWSSoapClient(MyHttpBinding, MyAuthASMXWebServiceAddress);

        Console.WriteLine(svc.HelloWorld());
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

I still doesn't know what means BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly and what are the another options, how they work. But, for now, it worked.